# uWSGI is ignoring uid, gid and chown-socket

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to use uWSGI with nginx.  The root problem I am having is that I'm getting "No such file or directory" from nginx trying to connect to the uWSGI socket file.

When I use the following settings, I am expecting the socket file's permissions to change.  However, they aren't.  It continues to show `uwsgi:uwsgi`.

The error from nginx is `*17 connect() to unix:/tmp/myapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.122, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/myapp.sock:", host: "192.168.1.123:81"`

myapp.ini (uwsgi)

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/local/myapp
plugins = python
module = wsgi:app
home = /var/local/virtualenv/myapp
file = main.py
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/myapp.log
pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi/myapp.pid
socket = /tmp/%n.sock

chmod-socket = 777
chown-socket = webuser:nginx
uid = webuser
gid = nginx

vacuum = true
```

file permissions

```
srwxrwxrwx.  1 uwsgi uwsgi    0 Jul  3 12:43 myapp.sock
```

myapp.conf (nginx)

```
server {
    listen 81;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp_error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @yourapplication;
    }

    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
usermod -a -G nginx uwsgi
usermod -a -G uwsgi nginx
useradd webuser
usermod -a -G nginx webuser
usermod -a -G uwsgi webuser
```

and I tried this:

```
grep avc /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nginx
semodule -i nginx.pp
```

**EDIT**

and I tried moving the sock file to `/var/run/uwsgi/myapp.sock`.  In that case, nginx tells me: `connect() to unix:/var/run/uwsgi/myapp.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream`

**EDIT 2**

and just for kix, I tried to use TCP port instead of a socket file.  In that situation, I can use `curl -XGET http://localhost:8000` and get the proper HTTP response from uwsgi/python.  However, in the nginx log (when attempted to come in via the browser through nginx, I get: `*1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream` The nginx file is configured like this: `uwsgi_pass uwsgi://localhost:8000;`

Comment: That nginx can't speak TCP to uwsgi is because of [a bug in uwsgi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27342256/1068283) and it has a workaround.

Comment: OK When I used the fix for the TCP bug, the error is now: `upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream`, but retrieving via `curl` still works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put sockets for interprocess communication in `/tmp`.

RHEL/CentOS 7, Fedora, etc., use [private /tmp directories](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/04/09/new-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-security-feature-privatetmp/), meaning each daemon configured for it (in this case, at least nginx) has a completely different view of `/tmp` than any other.

To resolve the problem, either place the socket in another directory or use TCP connections.

And don't blindly `audit2allow` things without understanding what's going on. You'll likely open up some security hole.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why it won't work in /tmp.  However, when I use /var/run/uwsgi/myapp.sock, I get (13: Permission denied) from nginx.

Comment: Try renaming the directory `wsgi` instead of `uwsgi`. And when it works, report this to Dan Walsh.

Comment: It did get things to finally change.  Now I'm getting: `connect() to unix:/var/run/wsgi/myapp.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work with uWSGI listening on a TCP socket instead!

Comment: I'm switching back and forth.  When I put it into socket file mode, I get these message.  And when I use TCP socket mode, I get the other ones.  :-)

Comment: I'm on v2.0.9.  If that helps.